# Is Winium an effective desktop application automation tool? Are all the objects in any standalone application identified by the Winium?

Tags: automation, automated-tests

Is `Winium` an effective automation tool for standalone application ?

Are all the elements in a standalone application identified by the `Winium`?

I have to select an automation tool which will be free. Kindly let me your valuable suggestions. Also give me some insights about White framework.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: do you use it, is it better than skiuli ?

Comment: Hi Emna.. Apologies for late reply. I havent used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go ahead with hybrid frame work .I tested our application in winium .It only didn't support Flash images then . But supports for all other fields .

Initially it looks little bit tough while you will go ahead solving issues will be easier . If you need the frame work I can Help also . Provide your mail Id .

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?